# Inverse Limit of $K[x,y]_{g}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm wondering if it is possible to obtain the ring $K[x,y]$, where $K$ is a field, as :

$$\varprojlim K[x,y]_{g}\text{,}$$

where $K[x,y]_{g}$ is the localization of $K[x,y]$ by the multiplicative system defined by $g\in K[x,y]$, and where each element $g$ verifies that the basic open set $D(g)$ is included in $\text{Spec}(K[x,y])-\{0,0\}$.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't understand how you're defining the multiplicative system.

Comment: $\{1,g,g^2,g^3,...\}$

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are thinking of something akin to $\bigcap \mathbb Z_p = \mathbb Z$ but for $K[x,y]$. (Here I mean $\mathbb Z_p \subset \mathbb Q$ is the set $\bigcup p^{-k}\mathbb Z$.)

$K[x,y]$ is a UFD, so just take an infinite set of (pairwise) relatively prime polynomials and it will work just the same.